# StreamPoints adding extra information

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Why doesn't the red line start precisely at the defined point $(0, 2)$ and go off to infinity?

My initial condition is $(0, 2)$ and I only want to see where that trajectory goes off to.

```
  StreamPlot[{1, y (y - 1)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, - 5, 5}, 
   StreamPoints -> {{{{0, 2}, Red}, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Why did it add everything before that? What would be nice is to show the initial point as a point on the phase portrait in red at $(0,2)$ and then the red line that goes off toward infinity.

Comment: In other words, you want the red streamline to only be traced forward and not backward from the point $(0,2)$?

Comment: @Rahul: That is correct. I could have sworn that previous versions did not go backward in time, so it seems like something changed in newer versions that automatically does that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you understand why, so I will focus on the part of the question that is constructive: how to draw the phase portrait that you've described.

One approach is to concatenate one `StreamPlot` that only draws the red line with another `StreamPlot` that draws all the other arrows. However, care has to be taken so that there is room for the red arrow in the second `StreamPlot` and also so that the size of the red arrows is the same as the size of the rest.

```
sp = StreamPlot[
  {1, y (y - 1)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  StreamPoints -> {{{{0, 2}, White}, Automatic}},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 2}]}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sp2 = StreamPlot[
  {1, y (y - 1)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  StreamPoints -> {{{{0, 2}, Red}}},
  RegionFunction -> (# > 0 &)
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[sp, sp2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, I could have sworn this didn't go backward in time and add that extra information in previous versions, but this gets the job done!